# Can user defined literals have functions as arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

**Can functions be used with user defined literals?**

If so, what shenanigans can be done? Is this legal?

```
void operator "" _bar(int (*func)(int)) {
  func(1);
}

int foo(int x) {
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  foo(0);    // print 0
  foo_bar;   // print 1
}
```

Comment: I think the arguments to `""` user defined literals are always `char*` and `size_t` aren't they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the C++11 Feb 2011 Draft § 2.14.8, the user literal types are integer-literals, floating-literals, string-literals, and character-literals.  There is no way to do a function-literal type.

> A user-defined-literal is treated as a call to a literal operator or
>   literal operator template (13.5.8). To determine the form of this call
>   for a given user-defined-literal L with ud-suffix X, the
>   literal-operator-id whose literal suffix identifier is X is looked up
>   in the context of L using the rules for unqualified name lookup
>   (3.4.1). Let S be the set of declarations found by this lookup. S
>   shall not be empty.

Integers:

```
operator "" X (n ULL)
operator "" X ("n")
operator "" X <’c1’, ’c2’, ... ’ck’>()
```

Floating:

```
operator "" X (f L)
operator "" X ("f")
operator "" X <’c1’, ’c2’, ... ’ck’>()
```

String:

```
operator "" X (str, len)
operator "" X <’c1’, ’c2’, ... ’ck’>() //unoffcial, a rumored GCC extension
```

Character:

```
operator "" X (ch)
```

Comment: Right, function names are identifiers, not literals.  Thus user defined *literals* doesn't apply to them.

Comment: @MichaelPrice That's a great way to put it.

Comment: It seems like any legitimate use I could think of for wanting "function literals" should be handled by lambdas anyway though, right?

Answer (score 1):

Look at `foo_bar`, its just a single lexical token. Its interpreted as a single identifier named `foo_bar`, not as `foo` suffixed with `_bar`.

Answer (score 1):

No.

C++ intentionally avoids such shenanigans since the symbol foo_bar would be very difficult to comprehend if it weren't defined immediately before its use in your example.

You could achieve something similar with the preprocessor.

```
#define bar (1)

int foo(int x) {
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  foo(0);    // print 0
  foo bar;   // print 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this adds anything but there's nothing preventing you from defining

```
PythonScript operator"" _python(const char*, std::size_t len) {...}

R"Py(
  print "Hello, World"
)Py"_python;
```

I actually think user-defined literals would make a nice way to embed scripts or SQL.